# HTML JavaScript print from file onto page

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with a little site (it's intended to work as a local site) I try to create.
I want it to print text from local txt file onto the page. I want it to display it like this one,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var arr = ['Heading 1','Para1','Heading 2','Para2','Heading 3','Para3'];
var result = arr.map((val, i) => i%2===0 ? `<h2>${val}</h2>` : `<p>${val}</p>`).join('');
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = result ;
</script>
```

but I want it to do it from a file, like this one

```
<script>
 var fileInput = document.getElementById('inputfile');
 fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
     var file = fileInput.files[0];
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = function(e) {
         document.getElementById('output').innerText = reader.result;
 };
     reader.readAsText(file);   
 });
 </script>
```

I tried to merge them together like this

```
   <script>
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('inputfile');
    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        var file = fileInput.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = reader.result.split("\n").map((val, i) => i%2===0 ? <h2>${val}</h2> : <p>${val}</p>).join('');
        };
    reader.readAsText(file[0]);   
 });
 </script>
```

But something is still not working right (after choosing the file to read, it does nothing) and I am not sure what am I doing wrong. I am green in javascript, so I would appreciate any help in that matter.

Comment: does the user uploads a txt file to the input field?

Comment: I just tried and your 2nd example works for me - do you get anything into your console? Also is your script the last thing on the page?

Comment: @vsync Yes, user inputs the text into the file

Comment: @Joel the 2nd one only reads the file as a string and prints it that way, while I need it to read it into array so I could modifie the output, just like in the first one. That's where the problem is.

Comment: well, this question is not about files at all but about parsing text into segments. The file upload part here is irrelevant

Comment: @vsync Yes, that right. I didnt knew how to put it in words so it would be clear what outcome I am looking for, so I gave those as to show it instead

Comment: I think the issue is still with with the file reading; I added an answer that I tested locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, now that I read that again - the only issue with your example is you were using `file[0]` instead of `file`

```html
    <input type="file" id="inputfile" />
    <p id="output"></p>
    <script>
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('inputfile');
    fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        var file = fileInput.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = reader.result.split("\n").map((val, i) => i%2===0 ? `<h2>${val}</h2>` : `<p>${val}</p>`).join('');
        };
     reader.readAsText(file);   // HERE! 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @To be honest, that one is still not working as I wanted it to (nothing is printed onto page after file selection, just like before), but the first one was working exactly as I needed it to, so thanks a lot

Comment: @OnionOfDoom Allright, hmm - I think there is still something then that is not perfect in this solution. I think I am missing or misunderstanding something, but I'm glad you got it figured out. May your layers be strong and your core full of doom - good luck

Comment: @OnionOfDoom I think I fixed it, try to run the snippet now - I was missing backticks (`) for the template literal... whoops!

Comment: Yup, that one works as well. Good to know that I was stuck for a few days on 4 missing backticks and and unnecessery "[0]". Looks like there is a long way ahead of me then, but still, thanks a lot for Your help

Comment: Ce'st la programming @OnionOfDoom - Especially with JavaScript :D